# Операции над строками

Tags: c#

1. Выведите на экран по одному разу в алфавитном порядке все строчные латинские буквы, входящие в заданную строку.
2. Подсчитайте сумму чисел, встречающихся в строке. Символ ‘–’ перед числом считается знаком отрицательного числа. Все остальные символы (кроме цифр и минуса) считаются разделителями между числами.

Помогите решить плиз!

Comment: @CyberFly, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В первом случае, наверное, можно использовать List<char>, сложить туда последовательно чары из строки предварительно проверив что такого чара ещё нету, потом отсортировать лист и вывести его последовательно.

Во втором случае можно воспользоваться функцией "string".Split для разбития строки на числа, и потом получить сумму используя double.Parse от полученных элементов массива.